# How to create an Azure ARM Virtual machine with License type using Java SDK?

Tags: java, azure, azure-resource-manager

Is it possible to create a **Virtual Machine** in **Azure (ARM)** with license type specified? I was referring below link for my reference example.

[azure-sdk-for-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/azure-samples/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/samples/CreateVirtualMachinesUsingCustomImageOrSpecializedVHD.java)

I am testing with **jdk 1.8**, and **Azure SDK Version 1.0.0-beta2**.

```
 VirtualMachine windowsVM = azure.virtualMachines().define(windowsVMName)
 .withRegion(Region.US_EAST)
 .withNewResourceGroup(rgName)
 //  .withExistingResourceGroup(rgName)
 .withNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")
 .withPrimaryPrivateIpAddressDynamic()
 .withoutPrimaryPublicIpAddress()
 //.withStoredWindowsImage("imgUrl")
 .withPopularWindowsImage(KnownWindowsVirtualMachineImage.
                                 WINDOWS_SERVER_2012_R2_DATACENTER)
 .withAdminUserName(userName)
 .withPassword(password)
 .withSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.STANDARD_D3_V2)
 .create();
```

Answer (score 0):

As to the technical possibility, you can create an Azure VM in ARM using your own image, but you need to [create & upload a Windows Server VHD to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-classic-createupload-vhd).

As to the license possibility, please see the details in the FAQ [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/licensing-faq/) for Windows Server license.